# Input not re-rendering onChange with hooks

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, onchange, use-state

When typing and logging the input e.target.value, I get the default value + the last key stroke, but nothing re-renders. I guess that React doesn't recognize that the state changed, but I'm having a problem finding out the correct way to do this.

This is the code in question:

```
  const [text, setText] = useState(task.text);
  console.log(text);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  const taskInput = (
    <form>
      <input type='text' value={text} onChange={handleInputChange} />
    </form>
  );
```

And the full file:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { TaskContext } from "../context/TaskState";

const Task = ({ task }) => {
  const { deleteTask } = useContext(TaskContext);
  const { changeStatus } = useContext(TaskContext);

  const taskText = (
    <div
      className='task-text'
      onClick={() => changeStatus({ ...task, done: !task.done })}
      style={task.done ? { textDecoration: "line-through" } : null}
    >
      {task.text}
    </div>
  );

  const [text, setText] = useState(task.text);
  console.log(text);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  const taskInput = (
    <form>
      <input type='text' value={text} onChange={handleInputChange} />
    </form>
  );

  const [option, setOption] = useState(taskText);

  return (
    <div className='task-container'>
      <button className='task-edit' onClick={() => setOption(taskInput)}>
        edit
      </button>
      <button className='task-delete' onClick={() => deleteTask(task.id)}>
        x
      </button>
      {option}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

I'am using global state for the rest of the app and reducers.

Comment: First I would advise against holding elements in state as option. Make option a primitive like boolean or `[option,...]=useState('taskText')`. Then on click change it. The conditionally render `{ option === 'taskText' ? taskText: taskInput}`. Also good to make taskText and taskInout functions too.

Comment: @kimobrian254 Thanks for helping out!

I made option a boolean, and changed the onClick event, but when I made the taskText and taskInput functions I got an error: 

**index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.**

When I conditionally tried to render them as components <TaskText/> and <TaskInput/>, the onClick event stopped working, but react rendered <TaskText/>. 

The same thing happened before I converted them into functions.

Comment: You don't render the function name, you render the call(return value) so instead of `{taskText}` you render `{taskText()}`. Then since you made option a boolean, make your onClick use it like this `onClick={() => setOption(false)}`. It starts by rendering taskText(assuming option is default true `const [option, setOption] = useState(true);`) and when you click it renders taskInput since option changes to false so `{option ? taskText: taskInput}` should work as expected @Aleksandar Andonovic

Comment: @kimobrian254 The first solution, when making option just a simple boolean didn't work, but **[option,...]=useState('taskText')** did!

The problem was in the way I passed option down in the jsx. As soon as I passed it conditionally, it fixed my input problem as well. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, I would appreciate an upvote.

Comment: I'm googling how, but I believe that I still don't have that option because I just lurked here and didn't build up enough reputation. I'll come back as soon as I do.

Comment: It's fine, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

I think, `onChange` in your input might cause this error. Try replacing this:

```
onChange={handleInputChange}
```

with this:

```
onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
```

`e` object might be not passed to your method.

Answer (score 0):

Please try wrapping your taskInput value in `useMemo` with dependency `text` as when you store JSX as variable during re-render they are refering to the previous value as they don't know the variable they used have value changed.

```
 import React, { useMemo, useContext, useState } from "react";
 
 const taskInput = useMemo(() => (
    <form>
      <input type='text' value={text} onChange={handleInputChange} />
    </form>
 ), [text]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way I passed option inside the jsx.

I made the option state a boolean, converted taskText and taskInput to functions and passed option conditionally inside the jsx.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { TaskContext } from "../context/TaskState";

const Task = ({ task }) => {
  const { deleteTask } = useContext(TaskContext);
  const { changeStatus } = useContext(TaskContext);

  const taskText = () => {
    return (
      <div
        className='task-text'
        onClick={() => changeStatus({ ...task, done: !task.done })}
        style={task.done ? { textDecoration: "line-through" } : null}
      >
        {task.text}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const [text, setText] = useState(task.text);
  console.log(text);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  const taskInput = () => {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type='text' value={text} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      </form>
    );
  };

  const [option, setOption] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className='task-container'>
      <button className='task-edit' onClick={() => setOption(!option)}>
        edit
      </button>
      <button className='task-delete' onClick={() => deleteTask(task.id)}>
        x
      </button>
      {option ? taskText() : taskInput()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Task;
```